# ansible loop through command for multiple hosts

Tags: ansible

Playbook

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: check for server ssh
      wait_for:
        port: 22
        host: "{{ item }}"
        state: started
        search_regex: SSH
        delay: 5
        timeout: 300
      register: ssh_out
      ignore_errors: true
      with_items:
        - 192.168.153.31
        - 192.168.153.32

    - lineinfile:
        line: "{{item.state}}"
        path: /home/ubuntu/playbooks/log/ssh_log
        create: yes
      loop: "{{ ssh_out.results }}"
```

Error: 'PermissionError' object is not subscriptable. I would like to loop through the ssh_out results and write log file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hosts` to loop over hosts.  That's what Ansible DOES.

```
---
- hosts:  192.168.153.31, 192.168.153.32all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: check for server ssh
      wait_for:
        port: 22
        state: started
        search_regex: SSH
        delay: 5
        timeout: 300
      register: ssh_out
      ignore_errors: true
```

To get the output into the log:

```
    - lineinfile:
        line: "{{ssh_out.results.state}}"
        path: /home/ubuntu/playbooks/log/ssh_log
        create: yes
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: I want to loop through the results, and write log using lineinfile..... I dont want to\ change the way to check the wait_for....

Comment: I will add the `lineinfile`, but you should be able to figure that out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

By default Ansible sends output about plays, tasks, and module arguments to your screen (STDOUT) on the control node. If you want to capture Ansible output in a log, you have three options:

To save Ansible output in a single log on the control node, set the log_path configuration file setting. You may also want to set display_args_to_stdout, which helps to differentiate similar tasks by including variable values in the Ansible output.

To save Ansible output in separate logs, one on each managed node, set the no_target_syslog and syslog_facility configuration file settings.

To save Ansible output to a secure database, use AWX or Red Hat Ansible Automation Platform. You can then review history based on hosts, projects, and particular inventories over time, using graphs and/or a REST API.